# Find when a Youtube video was uploaded using Selenium (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a script in python to go to a url that will show new YouTube videos, I'm wanting to find a video that says it was uploaded "3 minutes ago" and then print something in my console. [Example of mins ago](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTyJk.jpg)

I found this piece of Javascript code from a while ago, I'm not sure if this would be possible to be translated into Python code or not though. It finds a video that was uploaded from 3 minutes and under, meaning if a video was uploaded 2, 1 mins ago, or seconds ago, it will click on it.

```
var Link = iimGetLastExtract(2);
if (Link.indexOf("&") > -1) Link = Link.split("&")[0];

if (iimGetLastExtract(1).trim() == "2 minutes ago" || iimGetLastExtract(1).trim() == "1 minute ago" || iimGetLastExtract().indexOf("second") > -1)
```

Does anyone know how I could do this in Python? My code is below (not working since I don't know how to do this).

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

find_timeago = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[2]')

while True:
    if find_timeago == "3 minutes ago":
        print('found video from 3 mins ago')
    elif find_timeago == "1 minute ago":
        print('found video from 3 mins ago')
    elif find_timeago == "seconds ago": 
        print('found video from seconds ago')
    else:
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.refresh()
```

Answer (score 1):

if your js code is correct you can simply use it without having to translate it to python

js code

```
var Link = iimGetLastExtract(2);
if (Link.indexOf("&") > -1) Link = Link.split("&")[0];

if (iimGetLastExtract(1).trim() == "2 minutes ago" || iimGetLastExtract(1).trim() == "1 minute ago" || iimGetLastExtract().indexOf("second") > -1){
return iimGetLastExtract(1).trim()}
```

python code

```
x = driver.execute_script(js_code)
print(x)
```

x should hold what ever value evaluated to correct

Answer (score 0):

If your code for finding the span is correct, the code you should use is

```py
find_timeago = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[2]').text
```

instead of

```py
find_timeago = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[2]')
```

*P.S. You nearly always want .text or .find_element behind the result*

*And(though I don't know about YouTube), you don't need to use selenium, requests with headers is nearly always enough.*

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[2 and text()="3 minutes ago"]')))
    print('3 minutes ago')
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Should wait for the element or throw an error